# How to embed dynamic Ruby code to "javascript" section in Slim templates?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, slim-lang

One way:

```
javascript_tag do
  == "var all_product_ids = #{existing_ids.to_json};"
  == "var products_json   = #{@filter.data.to_json};"
```

or:

```
= %Q{
var all_product_ids = #{existing_ids.to_json};
var products_json   = #{@filter.data.to_json};
}
```

are there any better solutions for this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

what i prefer to do, is to keep all the javascript in a separate file.

for example, i would do it as follows(jquery):

in your layout:

...

```
<body data-product-ids="<%= existing_ids.to_json %>"
      data-products-json="<%= @filter.data.to_json %>">
```

.. in js:

```
// create your application namespace
$.myapp = {};
$.myapp.allProductIds = $.parseJSON( $('body').attr('data-product-ids') );
$.myapp.products = $.parseJSON( $('body').attr('data-products-json') );
```

so, you'll then use it in js like so:

```
$.myapp.allProductIds
```

Comment: Thank you!
But when you only need one or two lines js code, will you still use a separate file?

Comment: Well, yes, it's just for a "best practices" matter. But still, that makes your code more solid and better structed

Comment: Why this is the accepted answer when this is an ERB/jQuery answer to a specific slim/javascript question...

Answer (score 85):

In Slim

```
javascript:
  var all_product_ids = "#{existing_ids.to_json}";
  var products_json   = "#{@filter.data.to_json}";
```

Answer (score 20):

```
javascript:
  var all_product_ids = #{raw existing_ids.to_json};
  var products_json   = #{raw @filter.data.to_json};
```

Comment: be careful about the `</script>` attack

Comment: check Rails api for method `sanitize`

Comment: This throws `Uncaught SyntaxError: unexpected token: identifier` in then browser. I think it requires quotes.

Answer (score 18):

From https://github.com/slim-template/slim 
Text Interpolation paragraph

SLIM escapes HTML by default.
To avoid the same use **#{{content}}** for **#{content}**

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem with this. Using the code that others have provided didn't work for me because slim was html escaping my variable. I ended up using [Gon](https://github.com/gazay/gon-sinatra). This one is for Sinatra, but they have a gem for Rails as well. Hope it helps others having similar problems.

Answer (score 3):

create a `_your_erb_file_contain_javascript_code.erb` first

And then in your slim file `javascript:` part:

```
#{ conditions ? (render 'your_erb_file_contain_javascript_code') : nil}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
javascript:
  var isAdmin = "#{current_user.admin? ? 1 : 0}";
```