# how to embed the result of a Ruby variable in a slim Javscript block

Tags: ruby-on-rails, slim-lang

I have a Rails app that uses slim for templating. I'd like to have:

```
javascript: 
  window.ads.hasMap = ??? # value of show_map
```

like in .erb

```
   window.ads.hasMap = <%=show_map %>;
```

How would I do this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5646315/how-to-embed-dynamic-ruby-code-to-javascript-section-in-slim-templates, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17794403/ruby-inside-javascript-block-slim-template/25865643, https://github.com/slim-template/slim/issues/426 should all help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the docs](https://rdoc.info/gems/slim/frames), it looks like you want:

```
javascript: 
  window.ads.hasMap = #{show_map}
```

That is, wrap your ruby variable or method in `#{...}`.